# How do I resolve these CodeSign build failures?

Tags: iphone, xcode, provisioning

How do I resolve these CodeSign build failures?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sometimes get more verbose info about code signing errors from the system console (not the Xcode console).
A couple things to check into:

1. what type of provisioning profile are you using? if you're using ad-hoc, do you have an entitlements.plist?
2. Does the app identifier (com.yourcompany.appname) equal the app id you generated in the provisioning portal? it's case sensitive as well.

Good luck. Code signing/provisioning errors are a such a pain.

Comment: Yup, heres my entitlements.plist... http://d.pr/twjO
2. My app identifier is correct. o__o